# Node.js server files above root directory

Tags: node.js

I have the following directory structure:

```
limejs/
  closure/
    closure/
      goog/
        base.js
  projects/
    myGame/
      myGame.html
      server.js
```

I call "node server.js" in "cd limejs/projects/myGame". When I serve myGame.html, I want base.js to be included. Here's the script include from myGame.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../closure/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

The GET attempt is on localhost:8080/closure/closure/goog/base.js. I know that if I put my server code a couple of directories higher, I can access the base.js via:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/closure/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

But I'd like to keep all of the "myGame" related code in the same folder while experimenting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using `express.static(dir)`. Files are only served from `dir` down, everything else is invisible. Same goes for any other static file server (Apache, ningx, etc).

You need to either serve files from higher in the directory tree, so that `closure/closure/goog/base.js` is accessible (from `limejs` in this case), or copy/link the files into your game folder.

If you're on linux/mac, `ln -s closure/closure projects/myGame/closure` should do the trick, then you can include `<script src="closure/goog/base.js">`.

Comment: I ended up choosing "copy the files to your game folder" essentially. Although instead of copying the regular closure files, I installed nclosure as a node module.