# Node.js - Why does my HTTP GET Request return a 404 when I know the data is there @ the URL I am using

Tags: node.js, json, http, npm, request

I'm still new enough with Node that HTTP requests trip me up. I have checked all the answers to similar questions but none seem to address my issue.

I have been dealt a hand in the Wild of having to go after JSON files in an API. I then parse those JSON files to separate them out into rows that populate a SQL database. The API has one JSON file with an ID of 'keys.json' that looks like this:

```
{
"keys":["5sM5YLnnNMN_1540338527220.json","5sM5YLnnNMN_1540389571029.json","6tN6ZMooONO_1540389269289.json"]
}
```

Each array element in the keys property holds the value of one of the JSON data files in the API.

I am having problems getting either type of file returned to me, but I figure if I can learn what is wrong with the way I am trying to get 'keys.json', I can leverage that knowledge to get the individual JSON data files represented in the keys array.

I am using the npm modules 'request' and 'request-promise-native' as follows:

```
const request   = require('request');
const rp        = require('request-promise-native');
```

My URL is constructed with the following elements, as follows (I have used the ... to keep my client anonymous, but other than that it is a direct copy:

```
let baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/Users/doug5solas/sandbox/.../server/.quizzes/'; //  this is the development value only
let keysID = 'keys.json';
```

Clearly the localhost aspect will have to go away when we deploy but I am just testing now.

Here is my HTTP call:

```
let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: baseURL + keysID,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};
rp(options)
    .then(function (res) {
        jsonKeysList = res.keys;
        console.log('Fetched', jsonKeysList);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // API call failed
        let errMessage = err.options.uri + ' ' + err.statusCode + ' Not Found';
        console.log(errMessage);
        return errMessage;
    });
```

Here is my console output:

```
http://localhost:3000/Users/doug5solas/sandbox/.../server/.quizzes/keys.json 404 Not Found
```

It is clear to me that the .catch() clause is being taken and not the .then() clause. But I do not know why that is because the data is there at that spot. I know it is because I placed it there manually.

Comment: Clearly... either the url is wrong or your problem is not with the given code.

Comment: @Kevin B can you clarify? I built this environment on my local machine and I personally loaded the data so I could test the logic. And, I have commented out all but the code relative to this HTTP Request. The console output I show is my errMessage. So, I am not sure what you are telling me.

Comment: You are receving a 404 error from an http server. That means the server logic that is interpreting that http request is for some reason giving you a 404 response. That has literally nothing to do with the client making the request. (the client being the code you have provided in your question)

Comment: Assuming the url is correct, we can conclude that the problem is unrelated to the code you have provided (the question is therefore unanswerable in its current form)

Comment: My guess is you're using express or something similar (or just node.js and the http module) to create an HTTP server and haven't set it up to serve the given json file at that path.

Comment: I sort of see where you are going. What I am not understanding is -- 404 means resource not found, right? I am not understanding how it can be Not Found, when I know it is there. There must be some subtlety about a 404 that I don't understand.

Comment: well, it's less about the 404, and more about how urls and webservers work. A url doesn't necessarily match the filesystem that the http server is in. It's actually very common for a node.js server's urls to not at all match the filesystem structure.... so seeing the json file at that location in your filesystem doesn't necessarily mean the url will match the filesystem path.

Comment: I am using Express.

Comment: Are you using express.static to serve the folder the json file is in? how?

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. Not usre where to go from here.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Express.static, don't know about that. I will do some research.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [How to get files from server directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544628/how-to-get-files-above-the-server-directory-in-node-js/38544739#38544739)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kevin B for the tip regarding serving of static files. I revamped the logic using express.static and served the file using that capability and everything worked as expected.