# Why script tag with src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js" doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a test angularjs app from light-server (nodejs). Scripts are loading perfectly fine from cdn but when trying to load from ../directory it's giving 404. But it's working when loading from same level directory, I am confused why this is happening ?

`<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js></script>` doesn't work. Following two works.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js server files above root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335416/node-js-server-files-above-root-directory)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I start the server in a directory that server and all the child directories works fine but can't serve a file from ../ directory. But without the server when I'm loading the index file into the browser it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think, your ../node_modules not in http server, not served.